# PHP If statements not showing correct results

Tags: php

I have these PHP if statements, when i echo `$percentage` it shows 100 but its echoing

```
echo 'Over Allowance';
echo '<br>INSERT into customer_billing';
```

and not

```
echo 'Reached Allowance';

if($percentage >= '80' and $percentage <= '100') {
            echo '<strong>'.$customer["company"].'</strong><br>';
            echo 'Approaching Allowance';
            echo 'check customer_billing and remove';
        }
        //if its 100%
        elseif($percentage == '100') {
            echo '<strong>'.$customer["company"].'</strong><br>';
            echo 'Reached Allowance';
            echo 'check customer_billing and remove';
        }
        //if its more than 100%
        elseif($percentage > '100') {
            echo '<strong>'.$customer["company"].'</strong><br>';
            echo 'Over Allowance';
            echo '<br>INSERT into customer_billing';
        }
        //or if the limit is less than the percentage
        //this does nothing at all
        elseif($percentage < $result["soundfiles_max"]) {
            //do nothing
            echo 'check customer_billing and remove';
        }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: For starters $percentage <= '100' in first check should be $percentage < '100'

Comment: What exactly does `var_dump($percentage)` produce?

Answer (score 2):

you can remove the equal in first statment,

```
if($percentage >= '80' && $percentage < '100') {
```

Comment: If you don't do this you'll never get to the second elseif statement.

Comment: ok, that works however now $percentage is 10,025 and its not showing anything at all

Answer (score 0):

since you are using >= operators you should use integers not a text and remove '' on those number, so from '80' to 80 only

```
if($percentage >= 80 && $percentage <= 100) {
            echo '<strong>'.$customer["company"].'</strong><br>';
            echo 'Approaching Allowance';
            echo 'check customer_billing and remove';
        }
        //if its 100%
        elseif($percentage == 100) {
            echo '<strong>'.$customer["company"].'</strong><br>';
            echo 'Reached Allowance';
            echo 'check customer_billing and remove';
        }
        //if its more than 100%
        elseif($percentage > 100) {
            echo '<strong>'.$customer["company"].'</strong><br>';
            echo 'Over Allowance';
            echo '<br>INSERT into customer_billing';
        }
        //or if the limit is less than the percentage
        //this does nothing at all
        elseif($percentage < $result["soundfiles_max"]) {
            //do nothing
            echo 'check customer_billing and remove';
        }
```

Comment: Should not make a difference. http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: There is no difference in `And` and `&&` in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes around the numeric values like:

```
if($percentage >= '80' and $percentage <= '100') {
```

becomes:

```
if($percentage >= 80 and $percentage <= 100) {
```

Comment: If this one would cause the problem, he would see Approaching Allowance echoed.

Answer (score 0):

Omit quotes around percentage values because they are integers. Like

```
if($percentage >= 80 and $percentage <= 100)
```

if $percentage value is 100, it will not go to elseif statement, because you checked greater than equal to 100 in 1st statement.

Referring to [floating point numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php),

> never trust floating number results to the last digit, and do not
>   compare floating point numbers directly for equality. If higher
>   precision is necessary, the arbitrary precision math functions and gmp
>   functions are available.

Comment: $percentage is equal to '10,025' but its not displaying anything inside the if statements

Comment: Sorry i placed it under another user. Now you can see

Comment: Ok so do i need to do if($percentage > 80 and $percentage < 100) for the first one?

Comment: Yes and for comparing equal value, to check if($percentage==100) you can use if (abs($percentage-100) < EPSILON) { … } You can find more information in the link I wrote